# how to find parent and grand parent of an element without using xpaths

Tags: protractor

```
<button click-stop-propagation="" mat-button="" class="mat-button" ng-reflect-disabled="true" disabled="">
 <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
  <i class="icon icon-md delete-icon"></i>
  <span>Delete</span>
</span>
<div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="true" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div>
<div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
</button>
```

I want to find grand parent of `icon icon-md delete-icon` which is `mat-button` is there any way in protractor to do that, I want to avoid using xPaths.

I know that using xpaths I can do that element(by.css('.icon.delete-icon')).element(by.xpath('../..')); is there any way by which I can identify it using CSS ??

Comment: You want to make sure, that grandfather of `icon` is `mat-button` ?

Comment: No, I want to identify grandparent of `icon delete-icon` as this is unique. I know that using xpaths I can do that `element(by.css('.icon.delete-icon')).element(by.xpath('../..'));` is there any way by which I can identify it using CSS ??

Comment: From HTML that you provide i assume you can use element with className like this `element(by.className('mat-button'))`. If `mat-button` is not unique class, then you can always use full css selector for this button. Sometimes there is relative and shorter css selector for element. For example Firefox can provide it. If you go to Firefox DevTools, select element, right click it, then Copy in context menu, then Css Selector, then paste it in `element(by.css())`. You can do this in Chrome too, but Chrome always provide full css path, when Firefox try to provide shorter one.